# Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer' - how to fix

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to view and run the examples from the puppeteer files and it wont let me run the examples... I keep getting error messages:

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)



at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
```

Yarn is installed and the modules folder exist.
What do i need to do to correct this issue?

The repo was pulled from the main puppeteer github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Are you using webpack? How are you trying to run the examples?

Comment: i figured it out..... i need to run examles in the root folder and not in the example folder.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why does it not work in a subfolder...? It has to be in the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

When you make `git clone git@github.com:GoogleChrome/puppeteer.git` and after make `yarn install`, you are not installing puppeteer. You are installing the packages that was used to make this repo. In this case, puppeteer.

Since the examples use the 'puppeteer' npm package, you should install it explicitly with `npm install puppeteer` inside the repo folder. But before do that, you have to change the package.json "name" attribute from "puppeteer" to something else, like "puppeteer-repo". This has to be done to avoid package name clashing.

So, change the package.json "name" attribute and install puppeteer node package with `npm install puppeteer` inside the repo folder. After that, the examples should be working.